# Why does console.log inside this self invoking function not get executed?

Tags: javascript

The following code prints "true". I can understand why ff.f is equal to undefined, but I don't understand why console.log("Hi") is not executed inside ff.f when checking this value. Isn't f immediately executed upon definition?

```
var ff = function(){
    var f = function(){
        console.log("Hi");
    }();
};

console.log(ff.f === undefined);
```

[Edit] I guess a better way to ask this question is "When does this f function inside ff get executed?". I think it's weird that ff.f's value is "undefined" if it doesn't get executed until ff gets executed. Shouldn't it be the function instead?

Comment: The inner function is not referenced at `ff.f`. A local variable is just that, a local variable. In this case `ff.f` will always be undefined, because you never define it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not - it is executed once it is *evaluated* - which in this case is when the *parent* function (`ff`) is executed.

#### When is `f` executed

Any IIFE will be executed once it is evaluated - any such expressions included inside of other functions will only evaluated once the function it is scoped to (wrapped in) executes:

```
// Executed when the execution flow reaches this point
// i.e. immediately after the script starts executing
var outer = function() {
    console.log("Hello from outer");
}();

var wrapper = function() {
    // Executed when the flow reaches this point
    // which is only when the function `wrapper`
    // is executed - which it isn't, so this never fires.
    var inner = function() {
        console.log("Hello from inner");
    }();
};
```

#### Why `ff.f` is not a function

JavaScript is function scoped but JavaScript does not provide any way to *access* a function's inner scope (at least not, as far as I am aware).  So when you try to access `ff.f` you are looking for a *property* named `f` on the function `ff` - and by default there is no such property.  Even if you did:

```
var ff = function () {
    ff.f = function() {
        console.log("Hello from f");
    }();
};
```

`ff.f` would still be `undefined` (because the IIFE does not return anything).

Comment: so, you mean f gets executed when ff is executed? Then why is ff.f === undefined instead of ff.f being the function?

Comment: Ah I get it now! I think I got confused there for a bit. It makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: @pst - understood completely - I had another go at it - does the re-wording help?